# Can the order of fields/methods in generated WCF code be preserved?

Tags: c#, wcf, version-control, svcutil.exe

Whether I use "Service References" in VS 2010's Solution Explorer (which involves right-clicking the service reference I want to update and clicking "Update Service Reference") or I use svcutil.exe (which involves running the Visual Studio Command Prompt in Administrator mode and executing a batch file), the resulting generated code is totally mangled from a "lines changed" perspective, even if the real difference is just a line or two.

This makes merging awkward, because a simple change results in a totally new file, and hides the essence of the change when comparing changesets in our DVCS.

Why doesn't svcutil.exe (or other method) just process the wsdl top to bottom every time?

Comment: For generated code, you shouldn't generally be looking at performing merges - you should take one version or the other.

Comment: Either version on its own would be incorrect, thus necessitating an additional service reference update after the merge to account for changes on both sides.  If code generation was deterministic, merging would actually work fine.  For example, another code generation scenario is using sqlmetal.exe to generate a DataContext.  Since the tables and columns are processed in the same order every time, the resulting DataContext file can be easily merged.

Comment: @epalm Are you in control of the client code and the server code?

Comment: @epalm If you have control over the client and the server - I don't understand what the issue is. In the client project you track changes to the client code. In the server project you track changes to the server code. In both environments your changesets should have comments describing the check-in and you should be able to easily see what changes were made and why.

Comment: @eplam Also - I just wanted to note that I can't recreate the problem you describe. I use svcutil quite a bit to generate classes from XML schema files. In my experience, if I generate code from an schema file, make a change to the schema and then generate a new version of the code - those versions (of the code) are easily compared. I use Beyond Compare and the only differences are the changes that resulted from my update to the schema.

Comment: Your generated file probably isn't as big as my generated file :)

Comment: (By which I mean, the unordered nature of this issue suggests that somewhere, under the hood, there's a Set rather than a List.  Depending on the implementation, the Set may appear ordered...for a while...)